# Long running Node.js service to continuously make http requests

Tags: node.js

I'm beginning work on my first Node.js application and running into memory leak issues that i cannot pin down. I want the app to act as service in a way that continually runs and polls and endpoint. I think I may be missing something here. The idea of the project is to have a node application continuously make http requests to an Arduino board i have connected to my network with a web server on it. The networked board responds to the requests with some JSON or XML representing the state of the sensors attached to it. The idea of the node app is to log then emit sensor changes that will eventually be consumed by another electron project.

The node app is currently broken into a couple modules:

***proxy***: make the http calls to the different endpoints on arduino web server:

```
var http = require('http'), 
    KeepAliveAgent = require('keep-alive-agent');

var controllerRequestOpts = {};  

function send(path, cb){
  var response = '';

  //build the request
  var request = controllerRequestOpts;      
  request.path = path;

  //make the call to the controller
  http.get(request, function(res){
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        response += chunk;              
    });
    res.on('end', function(){                           
        cb(null, response);
    });     
  })
  .on('error',function(e){          
    cb(e, null);
  });
}

module.exports = function(controllerOptions){

  controllerOptions.port = controllerOptions.port || 2222;  

  controllerRequestOpts = controllerOptions;
  controllerRequestOpts.agent = new KeepAliveAgent();

  return{
    //JSON
    queryJson: function(cb){        
      send('/json', cb);
    },      
    //XML
    queryXml: function(cb){     
      send('/xml', cb);
    }
    //Additional endpoints
  }
}
```

***runner***: Loop forever with the interval provided making the proxy calls ot the arduino

```
var proxy = require('proxy');
var Watcher = require('./watcher');

var timer;
var toUpdate; 

function initProxy(controllerParams){
  proxy = proxy(controllerParams);
  Watcher = new Watcher();
}

function startListening(startOptions){
  var query;
  //determine the query and callback functions based off configuration
  query = startOptions.queryType === 'json'
    ? proxy.queryJson
    : proxy.queryXml;
  toUpdate = startOptions.queryType === 'json'
    ? Watcher.updateLatestJson
    : Watcher.updateLatestXml;

  //Start running and making requests every 15 seconds
  timer = setInterval(function(){        
    query(handleResponse);
  },startOptions.queryInterval);
}

function handleResponse(err, resp){
  if(err){
    console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
  }
  else{
    toUpdate.call(Watcher, resp);
  }
}

function stopListening(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  process.exit();
}

var runner = {
  connect: function(controllerParams){
    initProxy(controllerParams);
  },
  start: function(startOptions){        
    startListening(startOptions);
    return Watcher;
  },
  stop: function(){
    stopListening();
  }
};

module.exports = runner;
```

I have a "Watcher" module which is just a constructor function that emits the changes back to the calling app which looks like:

```
var runner = require('./index');

var controllerSettings = {
  hostname: '192.168.1.150',    
  port:2222
}

var startOptions = {
  queryType: 'json',
  queryInterval: 15000
}

runner.connect(controllerSettings);
var watcher = runner.start(startOptions);
watcher.on('P1Changed', printParams)
```

Everything is working as expected but as the app runs over time the memory usage for node process constantly increases. I'm wondering if i'm using either the http module incorrectly or if the runner shouldn't be doing a setInterval perhaps. Is there a standard way to run this kind of app as a 'service' and not so much as a 'server'

Answer (score 0):

Continuously send multiple HTTP requests will cause node to create huge TLSWrap objects that the GC will not be able to clear for several minutes.

If you wish to send data to the same host(s) over and over again, you need to open a TCP connection (stream) rather than use HTTP requests that have huge overhead.

Comment: So if I understand, I should use the net module to open a socket connection to my arduino host, write the http request then parse the response? Is there a way to keep the socket open to continuously keep writing the request? Does this inhibit the controller from responding to other normal http requests or posting data to other services while my socket is open?